# How to find all Event IDs in an efficient way?

Tags: r, web-scraping

How could I crawl this database with rvest to identify all tournament IDs for each year? Currently, I'm just going from 1:maxx(event_id), which is really a drain on compute time.

```
https://www.worldloppet.com/results/
```

The results filter seems to be dynamic on the webpage, so the url doesn't change.

```
outlist <- list()

for (event_id in 2483:2570) {
  event_id = 2483
  # update progress
  message('Retrieving Event ',event_id)
  
  race_url = paste0('https://www.worldloppet.com/browse/?id=',event_id)
  
  event_info = read_html(race_url) %>% 
    html_nodes('h2') %>%
    .[1] %>%
    gsub('<br>','<br>  ',.) %>%
    gsub("<[^>]+>", "",.) %>%
    str_split(.,'  ') %>%
    unlist()
  
  #event_info$eventid <- event_id
  
  outlist <- c(outlist, list(c(event_id, event_info)))
  
  # temporary break 
  Sys.sleep(3)
  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract all links containing the word browse from the HTML document:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'rvest'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:readr':
#> 
#>     guess_encoding

read_html("https://www.worldloppet.com/results/") %>%
  html_nodes("a") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  as.character() %>%
  keep(~ .x %>% str_detect("browse")) %>%
  paste0("https://www.worldloppet.com",.)
#>  [1] "https://www.worldloppet.com/browse/?id=2570"
#>  [2] "https://www.worldloppet.com/browse/?id=1818"
#>  [3] "https://www.worldloppet.com/browse/?id=1817"
#>  [4] "https://www.worldloppet.com/browse/?id=2518"
#>  [5] "https://www.worldloppet.com/browse/?id=2517"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! This gets the first page (which is the latest season) of results. How would you get the other seasons? They're in the database but don't show up until you filter for them.

Comment: You need to use RSelenium and a selenium server. Then you can write a macro clicking on the `race-year` element for you.

Answer (score 1):

The IDs of the rage can be found in the links, which can be extracted using the `html_attr` function. From there we can use some regex to find the numbers, here I include `id=` to make sure the page is an id, as I'm not sure whether you want to include links like `masters=9173`.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringi)
url <- "https://www.worldloppet.com/results/"
page <- read_html(url)
string <- html_attr(html_elements(page, "a"), "href")

matches <- stri_extract_all_regex(string, "(?<=id=).*", simplify = T)
as.integer(matches[!is.na(matches)])

# first 5
[1] 2570 1818 1817 2518 2517
```

Comment: Thanks! This gets the first page (which is the latest season) of results. How would you get the other seasons? They're in the database but don't show up until you filter for them.